# The dependency Owin 1.0 in project does not support DNXCore, Version=5.0

Tags: owin, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, dnx

I have upgraded my project dependencies from beta5 to beta6, including Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.

Now I'm getting some dependency errors on Microsoft.Owin 3.0.1, Microsoft.Owin.Security 3.0.1, Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook 3.0.1, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager 3.1.0 and Owin 1.0.

I didn't have this issue in previous upgrades.

My project.json file is as follows:

```
{   
    "version": "1.0.0-*",   
    "description": "",   
    "authors": [ "" ],   
    "tags": [ "" ],   
    "projectUrl": "",   
    "licenseUrl": "",

    "dependencies": {
        "WindowsAzure.Storage": "4.4.1-preview",
        "EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta6",
        "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-beta6",
      "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta6",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-beta6",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-beta6",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Facebook": "1.0.0-beta6",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Google": "1.0.0-beta6",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount": "1.0.0-beta6",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Twitter": "1.0.0-beta6",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta6",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-beta6",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-beta6",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta6",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta6",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta6",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-beta6",
        "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration": "1.0.0-beta6",
        "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-beta6",
        "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-beta6",
        "Microsoft.Framework.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-beta5",
        "Microsoft.Framework.Logging": "1.0.0-beta6",
        "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-beta6",
        "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-beta6",
        "Microsoft.Net.Http": "2.2.29",
        "Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook": "3.0.1",
        "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager": "3.1.0"   },

    "frameworks": {
        "dnx451": { },
        "dnxcore50": { }   } }
```

Comment: you should just remove this: "Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook": "3.0.1", from project.json, you already have the correct one "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Facebook": "1.0.0-beta6",

Comment: fyi beta7 is out so no reason to upgrade to beta6 you should upgrade to beta7

Comment: Thanks. It solved the Owin errors. Now it's down to just Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager 3.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

Beta8 is out, try the update. Additionally Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager in difference to e.g. "WindowsAzure.Storage (preview)" is not yet supported on the DNX SDK.